# r: Passing a list of columns through dplyr's group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr

First post, relatively new to R from SAS/SQL. I have a list of medical billing codes.My data are in a 'long' format, where I am getting one row of data that includes client identifiers, the date, and a single CPT code, along with the number of units and total cost.

Let's say my data contain a patient identifier (PTID), a program identifier (ProgramID), a date of service variable (DateService), a CPT code (ServiceCode), and the number of units charged (ServiceUnits). Let's ignore out cost variable for now.

For a given patient and visit, I would like to see the 'patterns' in what codes are being submitted to us. For example, if they are charging us for a specific kind of test, do they tend to also charge us for a certain type of specimen collection?

So, I have first converted my data from 'long' to 'wide' using dplyr and 'dcast':

```
claims3 <- dcast(claims2, 
   PTID + ProgramID + DateService ~ paste('Count', ServiceCode, sep =''), 
   value.var = 'ServiceUnits', 
   fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Then, I want to get the number of times each 'row pattern' appears in the dataset (minus identifiers). If you are familiar with SAS, I want something like the output from PROC FREQ with a LIST option on a multiway table. I've found a few different ways to do this, such as this one:

```
claims4 <- select(claims3, -PTID, -DateService, -ProgramID)
c <- claims4 %>% group_by(CountXXXXX, CountYYYYY, CountZZZZZ) %>% tally()
```

But, I'm trying to figure out how to use better coding to keep myself from individually listing all of the columns individually in the group_by clause. In my above example, I gave 3 different CPT codes. In reality, there are well over 50. This is my best attempt pass a list of column names through group_by at once. It fails:

```
claims4 <- select(claims3, -PTID, -DateService, -ProgramID)
varnames <-list(colnames(claims4))
c2 <- claims4 %>% group_by(varnames) %>% tally()
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I upvoted this...admittedly without reading the question (sorry!), but @jeff-hammerbacher's answer was exactly what I needed and the question's title (and google) got me here and solved my problem in no time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to your data but this works for me on the `mtcars` data. In your code, just use `colnames(claims4)` to keep `varnames` as a character vector, not a list. The idea is to convert your character vector to a vector of symbols with `syms`, then unquote that vector of symbols with `!!!`:

```
library(tidyverse)
varnames <- c("cyl", "am")
mtcars %>% group_by(!!!syms(varnames)) %>% tally()
```